# Javascript code throws exception - Access is denied. HTTPS only. Internet Explorer only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, https

We have our own http server adapter and we use that to host several sites.

This site runs over https. And it works fine when we try to access the url using chrome or firefox or safari. The problem happens only with IE (we test in IE11).

With IE - the page is getting loaded but it never completes and it gets hanged there only with the exception as - Access is denied - seen in the debugger. See the attachment.

[image]

We are totally clueless as why its happening only with IE.

Comment: It looks like you are rewriting contents in an iFrame using document.write. What is the original src of the iframe? If not https (for example nothing), you could try initialising it with a an empty page from your server

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have "pause on exception" true. Click on the symbol with the pause image and then press play (on the left).

It's the debugger causing you problems.

Comment: Thanks but I used debugger to show the problem. I know if I click play, it should work. But even after I click on play the screen gets hang there only. Need help.

Comment: Another thing to add. It works well when using http on IE but does not work when using https on IE and see Access is denied exception.

Comment: are you using iframes?